# Reactor Netty: independent DNS resolution for each connection in the pool

Tags: spring-webflux, netty, reactor-netty

I'm trying to create a Netty reactor `HTTPClient` for a host name `example.com` which resolves to multiple IP addresses. I want the http client's pool of connections to be evenly distributed across the IP addresses resolved by the DNS provider for the given host name.

By default, the DNS resolution picks a single IP randomly and all connections are resolved to the same IP. How do I do ensure a spread of IPs?